# android BitmapFactory always returns 0

Tags: android, android-image

I am using this widely know code

```
Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            float dw = display.getWidth();
            float dh = display.getHeight();

            // load image dimensions, not the image itself
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(MyApp.getImageFilePath());


            int heightRatio = (int) FloatMath.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight / dh);
            int widthRatio = (int) FloatMath.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth / dw);

            if ((heightRatio > 1) && (widthRatio > 1))// if true one side of the image is bigger than the screen
            {
                if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
                } else {
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
                }
            }
            // decode it for real
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize;
            bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; //http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmpFactoryOptions.inDither = true;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(MyApp.getImageFilePath(), bmpFactoryOptions);

            ImageView photo = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

the problem is that

```
bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth
bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight
bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize
```

always have the value `0`. I have tested it on three different devices, what am i doing wrong ?

and setting 
`bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize + 1;`

has no effect

Comment: what is `MyApp` here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what the title says, your BitmapFactory is returning a Bitmap just fine.

You never assigned your `bmpFactoryOptions` handle in this statement.  So querying it should produce no results.  Incrementing it doesn't help because you never initialized it to be the properties of an image.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(MyApp.getImageFilePath());
```

Do something like this instead:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(MyApp.getImageFilePath(), bmpFactoryOptions);
```

Which will attach your bmpFactoryOptions to your bmp.  Then you can query the options.  Note that your BitmapFactory is returning a perfectly good bitmap, just a bitmap where you don't have any handle to its properties.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's been bugging me for days, i used this Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(MyApp.getImageFilePath(), bmpFactoryOptions);